# Query list of ordered pairs in mysql / mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Im trying to query from de folowing structure:

```
idRoute | idCity | order
1         10       1
1         3        2
1         8        3
2         3        1
2         11       2
2         6        3
3         8        1
3         10       2
3         3        3
```

These are routes with some cities in particular order, although routes 1 and 3 have the same cities, the order makes them different.

Im getting an array with a new candidate route:

```
 [[idCity, Order]]
```

Ej.

```
[[10,1][11,2][2,3]]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to validate if the route already exists with a singe MySQL / MariaDB query?

Thanks in advance.

JC

Comment: you can use distinct, > select distinct idCity,order from Table

Comment: Thanks Imran, but using distinct was not the answer. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out using GROUP_CONCAT as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT kn_ruta_negocio, GROUP_CONCAT(kn_destino_entrega ORDER BY dn_orden_ruta SEPARATOR '') AS SURROGATE FROM ruta GROUP BY kn_ruta_negocio) RUTA
WHERE RUTA.SURROGATE = '151015181734167414961505175616971691';
```

Creating a surrogate key using all city keys made the trick.

Greetings.